# Open new console tab from within subpage

Tags: visualforce, visualforce-component, console

I have a visualforce page running within the Account page for which I want different behavior in and out of console.  When I'm in console, I want to be able to click on a link within the sub-page and use this to change the super-page's source.  I can't write any code directly on the super-page since it's the salesforce account page.
Two points:
1) sforce.console.isInConsole doesn't work - had to make a work-around.
2) running sforce.console.openConsoleUrl gives me the error Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'Listener' of undefined.
Is it possible to do what I want, or is it always going to look like a cross-domain forgery?

Here is the relavent code:

```
         <a href="#" onClick="navigateInConsole().bind(this);return false">{! lead['Id']}</a>
               <script type="text/javascript">

                    var iframeURL = this.parent.location.href;
                    var navigateInConsole = function navigateInConsole() {
                     var id = event.currentTarget.innerHTML
                     if (iframeURL.indexOf('isdtp') > -1) {
                         alert('in console');
                         sforce.console.openConsoleUrl(null, '/'+ id + '?isdtp=mn', true);
                     } else {
                         alert('not in console');
                         alert(this.parent.location.href);
                     }     
                    }
                </script>
```

Comment: Something seems wrong if sforce.console.isInConosole isn't working. Are you including integration.js in your page?

Comment: Yeah, if I hadn't included it, sforce.console wouldn't even be defined, sforce.console.isInConsole() returns "false" -> i think probably because the frame isn't in the "top level" of the console.